# How to remove visual gap between Positioned Widgets in Stack

Tags: flutter, dart

Even though there is absolutely no gap between my positioned widgets there is a glitchy visual gap between them. I have my Stack in an InteractiveViewer and when I zoom in and out and move about they become randomly more or less visible.

[image]

[image]

[image]

This happens with any Positioned widgets in a Stack so I've not provided any specific code of mine.

Answer (score 0):

This ui looks like there is nothing that's being stacked. If you are using positioned widget then the value given maybe a problem. For this layout you can try adding all images ina column